# Need to access a webapi server-side from a reactJS control

Tags: windows, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, server-side

I'm building a reactJS/aspnet5 site.  Where possible I'm trying to render my components serverside for responsiveness.  However I'd like to do an initial rendering, and then a more detailed rendering when a webapi call returns.  At the moment I have to fall back to client-side as follows:

```
class HomeComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {firstname : "fetching..."};
}

componentWillMount() {
    if (typeof(XMLHttpRequest) != undefined) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', '/Home/Me', true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState(data);
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>Name</h1>
          <p>{this.state.firstname} </p> 
      </div>
  );
}

}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is fulfill the request serverside or clientside, but XMLHttpRequest is, as I understand it, a browser facility.

I've attempted to use request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request ) but 2.69.0 fails to install and package correctly (npm and webpack, *on windows*), possibly due to a not-supported dependency, fs.

Does anyone know of a windows-compatible method of doing http requests both client and serverside?

Thanks